# python - Call a function with a specified variable name assigning value to that variable

Tags: python, function

I want to be able to pass in the name of variable to a function, and have that function call another function that calls the first function with a particular value assigned to the variable name. For example:

```
# function with argument 'arg2'
def foo(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print arg2

# function that calls foo with a value assigned to designated variable
def bar(var, value):
    foo(var=value)
```

So that when I call

```
> foo(arg2, 10)
```

I get the output

```
Output: 10
```

How is this done?

Comment: Can someone please explain what you are trying to do? Like, what do you want the code to run? Please explain it step for step like: You input a number, it prints the number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that, because it makes no sense; the name `arg2` would always refer to whatever the value of that variable is.

You can however pass the *string* `"arg2"`, and use kwargs to call the function:

```
def bar(var, value):
    foo(**{var: value})
```

although you would be better off doing this directly and removing the need for bar altogether.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem, I didn't know about kwargs, very useful. I am using this for a cross-validation function and needed it to be able to call arbitrary functions while varying values of arbitrary variables.